# Como implementar o metódo onBackPressed() em uma classe que herda de Fragment, Fazendo com que volte para o Fragment anterior?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

```
Segue um trecho de código para exemplificar meu problema:



public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment{
   ...

}


@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
   //Aqui volta para o Fragment anterior...
}
```

Dá o seguinte erro:

```
Error:(119, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```

Comment: Qual foi? pq me negativaram?

Comment: O trecho de código não tem implementação alguma, ai o erro fica sem sentido para analisar o problema.

Comment: @diegofm Qualquer que seja o conteúdo do método existirá sempre esse erro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Error:(119, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

O método `onBackPressed()` não existe na classe Fragment, portanto não pode ser sobrescrito(override).

Se quer poder voltar ao fragment anterior, via tecla *back*, chame o método [FragmentTransaction#addToBackStack(String name)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack(java.lang.String)) entre as chamadas a `beginTransaction()` e `commit()`.

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
...
...
...
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

Comment: Awwww entendi...Eu pensei em fazer implementação de alguma interface mas o problema é que eunão faço a menor ideia do nome da interface para implementar essa classe.

Comment: mas vem cá ramaral ali eu seto null naquele parâmetro é?

Comment: Vou ler a documentação...

Comment: Amanhã testarei e te sinalizo =D

Comment: Nesta situação pode passar qualquer valor. Um valor especifico só é necessário se quiser referenciar aquele *back state* futuramente.